# Can I add multiple users in the Managedby attribute in active directory?

Tags: active-directory

I am trying to use the active directory structure to keep the workers information of our company (names, phones, etc..).
Our layout is based on departments (each department is an OU) and within that department there are the user objects.

```
OU=Sales
  CN=John
  CN=Jane
OU=IT
..
```

I would like to define the ManagedBy attribute in the OU so I can write a powershell script to set the Person in charge for every person in the department, the problem is that in some cases there are two managers in the same department and the Parameter doesn't allow multiple values.
Might it be that I'm using the wrong tool?

Comment: Assign a group.

Answer (score 2):

That is a Single-Valued attribute, so it isn't possible to set multiple values.

Comment: Hi Joeqwerty, any ideas on other ways to accomplish the same then? Or should I go away from AD for this?